# Find and copy files contained in pathnames in a txt file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

We have a paths.txt file which contains pathnames of specific files in a folder.
    `asd/fold2/some.txt

     asd/fold2/some/tr6/ok.txt`
And we need to copy all the files listed in the paths.txt in a new folder .
My problem is not how to copy or move these files but how exactly i can find search and finaly get to move or copy them or whatever.

Comment: A bit confused. They are relaive paths? So do you want all the files in the same folder or do you want to rebuild the the folder tre somewhere else? i.e. Do you want to preserve or flatten the structure.

Comment: @PadAd : please modify your question to include the expected size of paths.txt, both as lines and # of characters. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-a` and `-I` options of `xargs` to do this:

```
xargs -a files.txt -I __FILENAME__ cp __FILENAME__ dest
```

Explanation:

- `-a`: Read items from file instead of standard input.
- `-I`: Replace occurrences of replace-str (in this case `__FILENAME__`) in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.

Answer (score 2):

You want that :

```
#!/bin/sh 
# usage : script.sh paths.txt destination
[ -f $1 ] || exit
[ -d $2 ] || exit

while read file
do
   cp $file $2
   echo "cp $file $2"
done < $1
```

Comment: some will complain about your use of `cat`, which can be replaced with `... done < $1` but I'll whinge about the use of a sub-process around your while loop :-). That is to say, I don't think you need the `( )` pair. Good arg trapping up front! Good luck.

Comment: @shellter you have right no need to use () (it's a bad habitude :) . I have also change for "< $1", it's more beautiful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without checking for duplicate names, it can be as simple as

```
cp $(<paths.txt) new_folder/
```